# How to separate the contents in an object that i have received from aspx web service to android?

Tags: android, asp.net, ksoap2

I am having a aspx webservice as provided below and an android program that consumes an object from that service. The android program consumes the object as:

```
anyType{Vehicle=anyType{VehicleID=KL-9876; VehicleType=Nissan; VehicleOwner=Sanjiva;};}
```

But now I want to separate each of the contents within the object. How do I do that

I tried getAttibute(0) just to check if i can get VehicleID separated but doesnt work...

My **aspx web service** is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebService4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public List<Vehicle> GetCustomerList()
        {
            Vehicle vehi = simpleCase();
            List<Vehicle> newL = new List<Vehicle> { vehi };
            return newL;

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Vehicle simpleCase()
        {
            Vehicle obj = new Vehicle();
            obj.VehicleID = "KL-9876";
            obj.VehicleType = "Nissan";
            obj.VehicleOwner = "Sanjiva";
            return obj;
        }
    }

    //someObject.SomeMethod(obj);

    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string VehicleID { get; set; }
        public string VehicleType { get; set; }
        public string VehicleOwner { get; set; }
    }


}
```

and my **android code** is as follows:

```
package com.example.objectpass;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView resultA;
    Spinner spinnerC;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] toSpinnerSum;
        toSpinnerSum = new String[9];

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinnerC = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        resultA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
//
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "GetCustomerList";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetCustomerList";
        final String URL = "http://192.168.1.104/WebService4/Service1.asmx";

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        //
        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
            SoapObject add = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(0);



            String xyz=add.toString();

            resultA.setText(xyz);
            // GetCustomerListResponse{GetCustomerListResult=anyType{Vehicle=null;
            // }; }
            //
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you fo for JSON?

Comment: @JayantVarshney Hey im new to web development, what changes do I need to make?

Comment: Make your Restful WCF by seeing  [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec) and see how to use it in your android program [here](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/)

Comment: @JayantVarshney Hey thanks, but instead of doing all that cant I simply separate the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have try to parse your response using following code snippet. It is not the final answer but it will solve 95% of your response.

```
SoapObject result;
    result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

    JSONObject tempJsonObject = null;
    String input = result.toString();

    String temp = input.substring(
            input.indexOf("GetCustomerListResult") + 28, input.length() - 2);
    input = null;
    System.out.println("String temp::**" + temp);

    try {

        tempJsonObject = new JSONObject(temp);


        String tempVehicle = tempJsonObject.getString("Vehicle");

        if(tempVehicle!=null){

        String innerTempVehicle = tempJsonObject.toString();

        String temp2= innerTempVehicle.indexOf("anyType") + 28, input.length());
        Log.i("Content of temp2",temp2);

        JSONObject tempJsonObject1 = new JSONObject(temp2);

        String tempVehicleID = tempJsonObject1.getString("VehicleID");
        String tempVehicleType = tempJsonObject1.getString("VehicleType");
        String tempVehicleOwner = tempJsonObject1.getString("VehicleOwner");




        }else{

            Log.i("Vehicle Error","Response Null");

        }
```